# Could all heuristic approaches, as UPGMA, provide different results in repeated analyses?

Tags: statistics, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering, heuristics

I would like to know if all heuristic approaches, but concretely UPGMA or affinity propagation may provide different results in repeated analyses if the groups are not highly defined.

I mean, as heuristic approaches are practical methods that cannot ensure an optimal, it is possible that in each repeated analyses we could obtain different solutions if there is no clear optimum, is it right?

Therefore I would like to confirm that this may happen for all heuristic approaches.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

What is a heuristic approach?

I would not call UPGMA a heuristic. It is a definition of cluster similarity, and since it is a definition it is exact. But it may be hard to find the global optimum for this *problem* using heuristic *algorithms*. Just like Lloyd's algorithm may not find the global optimum for k-means.

Single-link is about the only HAC method where you can guarantee to find the optimum, because it boils down to finding the minimum spanning tree. Yet, the MST may not be uniquely defined (and then two permutations of the same data set will not give the same result). And a tiny change to the data set (or, e.g., removing or adding a point) can yield a quite different solution. So I would rather talk about **stability, or robustness**. I don't think we can call any of the clustering algorithms "robust" statistics. Probably the most robust one is k-medians, as the median is known to be more robust than the mean.